# Where to get Audacity Stable?

Tags: audacity

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. According to the help menu in Audacity, it is version **2.0.6-alpha-May 31 2014**, and it has bugs and occasionally crashes in the middle of recording. Losing an hour of recording/edits is not cool.

Is there a ppa download for the stable [Audacity 2.0.5](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No PPA is needed.

In Ubuntu 14.04 Audacity 2.0.5 is available in the [universe Ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=audacity&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all).

You can install it from the terminal using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

Comment: You're right. Due to my upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04, I had a version of audacity from svn version. I had to use aptitude to downgrade the packages `audacity` and `audacity-data` to the version from universe repository.