# How can I slow down music with Clementine?

Tags: clementine

I want to slow down music while playing music with Clementine. How can I do it ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible currently. There is an open feature request: [Wishlist: tempo/pitch shifter](https://github.com/clementine-player/clementine/issues/984)

You could use Audacity to change speed/tempo. See [Where to get Audacity Stable?](https://askubuntu.com/q/486569/301745)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.seventhstring.com/xscribe/overview.html is of professional quality.
It's not for free, but absolutely worth it's price (lifetime license).